# How to alter standard.front_page in module links YML file?

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a menu with a "Home" link which was "provided by the Standard module. The title and path cannot be edited."

I am trying to alter the text/link using my module's links.yml file like so:

```
standard.front_page:
  title: 'Home Test'
  route_name: '<front>'
  menu_name: main
```

However this has no affect on the menu link. Other entries in this file work just fine.

Is it possible to alter the link in this way, or is the only option to use one of the menu hooks such as [hook_menu_links_discovered_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x)

Comment: do you found the solution?

Comment: Thank you, your answer was correct. It wasn't working at first due to a permissions problem. I was just hoping it could be changed directly in the yml links file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use this the [hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x) in this way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().
 */
function YOUR-MODULE-NAME_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
   // Changing the title.
   $links['standard.front_page']['title'] = 'Hi';
   // Changing the route.
   $links['standard.front_page']['route_name'] = 'block.admin_display';
}
```

But it seems that there are another ways in [How to update a menu link created with MenuLinkContent::create()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/225600/28275) and [How do I programmatically update or delete menu items?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/235516/28275)

Comment: Using this hook you can alter the 'main' menu items like standard.front_page (Home) and you can't do that in your hook_install implementation. Please see this answer for more about this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189471/50538